# Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. SQL Server Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to enter data using query string. My code is

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  insertData();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["SChn"]))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["PAN"]))
                    {
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["STag"]))
                            {
                                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["MAC"]))
                                    {
                                        insertData1();
                                    }
                             }
                    }
            }
    }
        //   else
        //  {
        //         Response.Redirect("http://localhost:53627/Default.aspx");
        //   }



    public void insertData1()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SensorConfig(SChn, PAN, STag, MAC) VALUES(@SChn, @PAN, @STag, @MAC)", con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SChn", Request.QueryString["SChn"].Trim()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PAN", Request.QueryString["PAN"].Trim()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("STag", Request.QueryString["STag"].Trim()));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("MAC", Request.QueryString["MAC"].Trim()));
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
                Response.Write("Unable To Save Data. Error - " + Ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //sets the connection string from the web config file "ConnString" is the name of the Connection String
        return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConsString"].ConnectionString;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        insertData1();
    }
```

I made some changes according to the suggestions but the error changed to

> `Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
>   I tried but not getting any clue.

Comment: Kindly go through the edit

Comment: First of all - you're doing it way too complicated - you could just use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@SChn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Request.QueryString["SChn"];` and the **main problem** I suspect is that some of your values from the request string might be null - in that case, no value is being added to the `Parameters` collection! You need to **check for NULL** on your query string values and provide a sensible default if that's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :**  you should provide the `Command Parameters` which are specified in SQL `INSERT INTO` Statement

You have given used insert into as below:

```
"INSERT INTO SensorConfig(Sensor_Channel, PAN_ID, SENSOR_TAG, MAC_Address) VALUES(@SChn, @PAN, @STag, @MAC)"
```

So you should provide  as below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SChn", Request.QueryString["SChn"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PAN", Request.QueryString["PAN"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STag", Request.QueryString["STag"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MAC", Request.QueryString["MAC"]));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Solution 2:** I think your 3rd Query String is `Request.QueryString["Stag"]` small s not Capital S Check it once

**Solution 3:**  change if conditions as below:

```
if ((Request.QueryString["SChn"] != null) && (!(Request.QueryString["SChn"].Trim().Equals(""))))
{
   if ((Request.QueryString["PAN"] != null) && (!(Request.QueryString["PAN"].Trim().Equals(""))))
   {
      if ((Request.QueryString["STag"] != null) && (!(Request.QueryString["STag"].Trim().Equals(""))))
      {
         if ((Request.QueryString["MAC"] != null) && (!(Request.QueryString["MAC"].Trim().Equals(""))))
         {
            insertData();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

while inserting data use `Trim`

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SChn", Request.QueryString["SChn"].Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PAN", Request.QueryString["PAN"].Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STag", Request.QueryString["STag"].Trim()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MAC", Request.QueryString["MAC"].Trim()));
```

Comment: @Downvoter : please check now and let me know if anything is missing

Comment: @Saumil: i think you are getting null when you use QueryString, could you please Debug and see what exactly QueryString gives?

Comment: I am checking if its null or not at the starting check the edited code

Comment: @Saumil: check my edited answer with section solution 2, check 3rd Query string parameter `Stag`

Comment: @Saumil: check your Query String whether is it `STag` or `Stag`?

Comment: @Saumil : then change if statement as  `if (Request.QueryString["STag"] != null)` while checking for null, then it works perfectly

Comment: @Saumil: use Trim function to avoid whitespaces check answer with solution 3.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. This is the error this time

Comment: @Saumil: which approach or whose solution you are using? could you please edit your question with latest code?

Comment: @Saumil: could you please try my approach?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41610/discussion-between-saumil-and-sudhakar)

Answer (score 3):

You used wrong sql parameter names

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SChn", Request.QueryString["SChn"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PAN", Request.QueryString["PAN"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STag", Request.QueryString["STag"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MAC", Request.QueryString["MAC"]));
```

you need to specify exact same names as in sql query

**EDIT**

add this before, if you pass normal null or empty value, you will get your error, so you need to pass `DBNull.Value` instead

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["SChn"]))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SChn", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SChn", Request.QueryString["SChn"]));
}
```

**EDIT2**

if your columns are `not null` columns change your code to:

```
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["SChn"]))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["PAN"]))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["Stag"]))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["MAC"]))
                {
                    insertData();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

because you want to add values only when they are not `null` and not empty

Comment: @wudzik: i dont think adding DBNull.Value solves the issue , if that is the case then null(returned by QueryString) should not have thrown exception, please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Sudhakar value can be also a `string.Empty` not only null. Adding DBNull.Value is just a proposed solution :) It will add value to database (so it's a solution is some way)

Comment: @wudzik: i think OP table columns are defined as `not null` that is why giving `DBNull.Value` may not solve the issue IMO what do you say? correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Sudhakar it's possible, but not mentioned. If they're marked as not null it's worth mentioning. I'll create new sample for that case. Thanks

Comment: @wudzik: yes OP should mention the Column Constraints, your code now looks perfect +1 :)

Comment: @wudzik: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` This is the error I am getting now

Comment: @Saumil in which approach and in which line?

Comment: @wudzik: The Edit2 approach unfortunately its not showing line on which the error is generated.

Comment: @Saumil I don't see any option when this will throw exception

Answer (score 2):

Change this code part. You should specify parameter name, not the column name.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SChn", Request.QueryString["SChn"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PAN", Request.QueryString["PAN"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@STag", Request.QueryString["STag"]));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MAC", Request.QueryString["MAC"]));
```

**EDIT:**

Some values can be empty string. You should change this code too

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["SChn"]))
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["PAN"]))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["Stag"]))
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["MAC"]))
                    {
                        insertData();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

More info on this

[SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What's the value for Request.QueryString["SChn"]? Is it empty?

Comment: I am checking if its null or not at the starting check the edited code

Comment: You're checking for null, but it can be an empty string.

Comment: @hgulyan: you are doing inverse operation , calling Insert function when everything is null.